# How to draw means graph with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

I need to draw a graph like above.

The number represents mean and the stick represents the 95% interval.

I can only do this with boxplot. How would i do this with sticks like the graph above instead of boxes.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.set_style("whitegrid") 
plt.ylim(0,130) 

ax = sns.boxplot(x='ING_PERCENTAGE', y='WTP_PREM%', showfliers=False, 
linewidth=0.8, showmeans=False, data=df)
ax = sns.pointplot(x='ING_PERCENTAGE', y='WTP_PREM%', data=df, ci=None, 
color='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is [seaborn.pointplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html?highlight=pointplot#seaborn.pointplot), the confidence interval is set in the ci parameter. to make sure you have the caps in the bar on the interval make sure you set capsize as well (in the example in the link, 0.2)